# Cоздание точек в matplotlib (выделение точек )

Tags: python, matplotlib

Есть программа, которая строит точки на графике в matplotlib и, согласно этой программе, при нажатии на точку появляются ее координаты. Координаты появляются только при нажатии на точку, если нажать на любую другую область графика ничего выводиться не будет, необходимо сделать так чтобы при нажатии на точку с координатами на ней создавалась еще одна точка ,но чтобы точки могли создаваться только на точках с координатами, в любой другой области графика создавать их не нужно

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.text import Text
from matplotlib.image import AxesImage
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

if 1:
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('click on points', picker=True)
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel', picker=True, bbox=dict(facecolor='red'))
line, = ax.plot(rand(100), 'o', picker=5)

def onpick1(event):
    if isinstance(event.artist, Line2D):
        thisline = event.artist
        xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
        ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
        ind = event.ind
        print( 'X='+str(np.take(xdata, ind)[0])) # Print X point
        print ('Y='+str(np.take(ydata, ind)[0])) # Print Y point


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: от `if 1` смешняво немного

Comment: очень путанно про еще одну точку на точке.

Comment: @strawdog я думаю здесь идёт речь про то, что мы *выделяем* нужную нам точку по нажатию.

Comment: @strawdog да, прошу прощения ,мы фактически создаем новую точку или выделяем старую , у которой есть координаты

Comment: яснее не стало. зачем создавать еще одну точку на уже существующей?

Comment: @strawdog для того чтобы после этого задать функцию, которая будет выделять все точки которые находятся  в диапазоне между этими выделенными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что вам нужно. Но допускаю, что вы имели в виду *выделение* существующей точки на графике, можно данного добиться следующим образом, вот ваш код:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.text import Text
from matplotlib.image import AxesImage
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('click on points', picker=True)
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel', picker=True, bbox=dict(facecolor='red'))
line, = ax.plot(rand(100), 'o', picker=5)

selected_point = None #создадим переменную для выделенных точек

def onpick1(event):
    global selected_point
    if isinstance(event.artist, Line2D):
        thisline = event.artist
        xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
        ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
        ind = event.ind
        print( 'X='+str(np.take(xdata, ind)[0])) # Print X point
        print ('Y='+str(np.take(ydata, ind)[0])) # Print Y point

        if selected_point:
            selected_point.remove() #уберём старое выделение
        
        #выделим новую точку
        selected_point, = plt.plot(np.take(xdata, ind)[0], np.take(ydata, ind)[0], 'ro') 
        plt.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick1)
plt.show()
```

Результат клика по точке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если данный ответ устроит вас, не забудьте [пометить его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Добро пожаловать на ruSO!

Comment: Cпасибо, это то что нужно, не могли бы вы подсказать еще как можно выводить координаты этих выделенных точек на самом графике ?

Comment: @Greg1402 официальная документация уже рассказала -> https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!